# twitter developer api oauth gives bad authentication data, but all good

Tags: python, django, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Trying to get Twitter to authenticate my get request to the new api for recent tweets around a particular topic. I have some issues with the authentication, that I can't seem to pin down. I authenticated my application using a client key and client secret, then authenticated a user and accepted that the app can read and write permissions. With the users authentication token and secret I tried to authenticate to get the data from the newish api and got bad authentication error.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?:

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=python' --header \

'authorization: OAuth \
oauth_consumer_key="i_put_api_key_here",\
oauth_consumer_secret="i_put_api_secret_here",\
oauth_token="i_put_user_token_after_accepting_app_can_make_changes",\
oauth_token_secret="i_put_oauth_token_secret", \
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",\
oauth_timestamp="",\
oauth_version="1.0"'

return data is:
{"title":"Unauthorized","type":"about:blank","status":401,"detail":"Unauthorized"}
```

I'm referring to this document: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a

I'm pretty sure I am supplying all the data it needs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Python saved the day. You can request a bearer token from the Twitter Api dashboard for the app. Then use OAuth 2.0 like so,

```
def get_data(url):
    headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer " + str(TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN) }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response_data = response.json()
    return response_data

get_data('https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query="Python";max_results=10')
Out[20]: 
{'data': [{'id': '1294146621652045826',
   'text': 'RT @jacoblawherlin: @Taco_Farmer1 Maybe this is why Python is so popular for data science but not software dev (in addition to performance)…'},
```